# Select max value of each group using partition by

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, group-by, common-table-expression

I have the following code which is taking a looong time to get executed. What I need to do is select the column having row number equals 1 after partitioning it by three columns (col_1, col_2, col_3) [which are also the key columns] and ordering by some columns as mentioned below. The number of records in the table is around 90 million. Am I following the best approach or is there any other better one?

```
  with cte as (SELECT
     b.*
    ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY col_1,col_2,col_3
                         ORDER BY new_col DESC, new_col_2 DESC, new_col_3 DESC  ) AS ROW_NUMBER
  FROM (
    SELECT
       *
      ,CASE
         WHEN update_col = '        ' THEN new_update_col
         ELSE update_col
       END AS new_col_1
    FROM schema_name.table_name
    ) b
  )
 select top 10 * from cte WHERE ROW_NUMBER=1
```

Comment: It would be tough to define an index to cover this query.  Do you really need to use `SELECT *` here?

Comment: what Tim said is a good start ... the SELECT * could be a problem... 
are you able to show us the execution plan?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I can do away with the `SELECT *` part. I am fetching 100+ rows here. I will try listing all out.

Comment: @RodneyEllis I am afraid I don't have the access to get the execution plan.

Comment: Well, if you don't have access to the execution plan how are do you expect to improve performance, by trial an error?

Comment: Applying filter ROW_NUMBER=1 first and then use CASE conditions may add some performance gain in script execution.

Comment: @mkRabbani Where do we apply the filter? Isn't it done the right way now?

Answer (score 0):

Currently you are applying CASE on different columns which is impacting all rows in the database table. CASE (String Comparison) Is a costly method.

At the end, you are keeping only records with ROW NUMBER = 1. If I guess this filter keeping Half of your all records, this will increase the query execution time if you filter (Generate ROW NUMBER First and Keep Rows with RN=1) first and then apply CASE method on columns.